# Catalog Price Rules conditions not working

Tags: catalog, catalog-price-rules, customer-group

When I create a catalog price rule everything works fine for a specific customer group.

As soon as I add a category condition nothing works. Has anybody experienced this before?

Conditions:
ANY are TRUE
Category (is, is one of, etc, tried all) is in category trying to target

Action
Reduce price by 15%

Products are in multiple categories.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your price rule in the question. There is a chance you are configuring it wrong.

Comment: @Marius conditions added!

Answer (score 4):

I hate to give a 'have you updated?' - "solution" but I cannot comment without posting it as an 'answer'.

There are several problems with Catalog Price Rules in 1.8 and 1.9.0.1 - Updating to 1.9.1 solves several issues with conditions.  Usually around overlapping rules.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce-19-1910-fixes-target

In regards to a working rule:
I would use the "is any of" condition for the "category" in your rule set.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to indicate the category not by it's name, but by it's category ID which Magento stores in the database.

If you need to find out what the category's ID is, simply navigate as follows:

`Catalog > Manage Categories`

Select your category on the left-hand side, once the AJAX has loaded you'll see the name of the category in bold text next to the category selection, with it's ID next to it.

Comment: I'm using the category ID's correctly, not the category names.

Comment: Understood. Make sure that you have the following set up:

`- Relevant customer groups selected for the rule,
- Status set to active
- From date populated
- Is one of selected for the conditions`

Thereafter, clear your cache & reindex all and the rule will be applied, Magento requires a complete reindex of the catalog for the rule to become active. (System->Cache Management & Index Management, just select all and refresh/reindex and you'll be all set.)

Answer (score 2):

"IS ONE OF" was fixed in magento 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Before changing anything else, check if your server's timezone matches your magento site's.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230478/magento-catalog-price-rules-not-working-half-a-day?rq=1